# How to upload files with the jquery $.post shorthand

Tags: jquery, ajax

This should be simple, but I'm not seeing any good syntax examples out there.

I have this super simple code that works great.  Uploads my data, response message shows in a specified div on my page.

```
    $("#my_form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission


    $.post( post_url, form_data, function( response ) {
      $("#my_results").slideDown();
      $("#my_results_inner").html( response );
   
    });
```

I'm repeating this form in another place, and that form also works great - but I need to upload a file in that instance.  As it stands right now, it appears that I'm only sending the text stuff - not the files, despite have the enctype and such set.

I see the long form ajax form stuff that says I should I should set the following:

```
 cache: false,
 contentType: false,
 processData: false,
```

Though it seems that most sources just mention the contentType.  Whatevs.

What I'd like to know is if I can pass that argument with my existing code without having to rewrite the whole thing in a long form $.ajax request.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, you need to set the `contentType` and `processData` properties to `false` to send a FormData object (note that this is the simplest way to send binary file data through AJAX, `serialize()` will not work out of the box).

You can't set those properties directly using `$.post()`. You could use `$.ajaxSetup()`, but this may affect any other AJAX requests you send within the page's lifetime so may not be a good idea.

The best approach is to simply use `$.ajax()`. Here's a working example:

```js
$("#my_form").on('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: e.target.action,
    data: new FormData(e.target),
    contentType: false,
    processsData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: response => {
      $("#my_results").slideDown();
      $("#my_results_inner").html(response);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That's what I was looking to know.  I can rewrite the thing as an $.ajax request, I was just hoping that I had overlooked some docs and could pass those config options to $.post.

Thanks for the swift answer.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Note my point about using `FormData` over `serialize()`, though.

Comment: Wow.  Working code, too?  You are a hero.

Comment: Well, maybe not working, but a great framework.  I'll figure out the bug.  Thanks again.